# jQuery validate error when select is added dynamically

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a form where blocks of HTML are added dynamically when someone wishes (for example) to "Add Another Adult" to a family.

I want each field to have a unique name, so I'm using a counter: the first name field for the first adult is 'firstName1,' for the second 'firstName2,' and so on.

Because I want to add custom messages to the fields (and the Validate plugin doesn't have a messages() method), I'm trying to add the rules immediately after the HTML is added to the DOM.

This works fine for text inputs, but throws an error for select elements -- 'TypeError: d is undefined'.

For example:

```
$("input[name='city" + counter + "']").rules("add", {required:true, messages: {required:"Please enter a city."
}});
```

... works fine. But ...

```
$("input[name='state" + counter + "']").rules("add", {required:true, messages: {required:"Please enter a state."
}});
```

... which identifies a select box, throws the error.

The behavior is consistent. There are several selects which are added, and adding a rule to any of them in the manner shown above throws the error.

I'll mention that all select boxes have an initial option with a value of "", so the required validation should work properly.

But of course, it never gets a chance. The error is thrown when the rule is added.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: It would be helpful to show the relevant part of the form (i.e. what is generated when you click Add Another Adult)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For selects you should use `select[name=foo]` instead of `input[name=foo]`:

```
$("select[name='state" + counter + "']").rules("add", {required:true, messages: {required:"Please enter a state."
}});
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the answer. I simply used the wrong reference to the element.